# failed to login to mssql docker database using DBeaver

Tags: sql-server, bash, docker, docker-compose, dbeaver

I have a problem with connection to MSSQL Docker database created from docker-compose.yml file and additional .sql file with ready-to-go empty database configuration. To connect to the MSSQL database i have used DBeaver. During the connection this error occured:

> Login failed for user 'system'. ClientConnectionId:23649321-6526-4ec2-a6ed-9943e64ca019

Probably i have wrong docker-compose.yml file or wrong .sql configuration file (.sql file should work with MSSQL format). .sql file is mounted in scipts folder inside mssql folder with .yml file.

docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  sql-server-db:
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "secret123new!"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
        TRUSTED_CONNECTION: "TRUE" 
    volumes:
    - ./data/mssql:/scripts/
```

.sql file:

```
CREATE DATABASE probna
GO
USE probna
GO
CREATE LOGIN system WITH PASSWORD='system'
GO
CREATE USER system FOR LOGIN system
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER system
GO
CREATE TABLE Products (ID int, ProductName nvarchar(max))
GO
```

If you have any ideas or fixes to existing code in .yml or .sql file please write a comment :)
Have a nice day !

PS. do you think this added to .yml file will work ?

```
  mssql:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest
    environment: 
      - SA_PASSWORD=Admin123
      - ACCEPT_EULA=Y
    volumes:
     - ./data/mssql:/scripts/
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c 
      - |
        # Launch MSSQL and send to background
        /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
        # Wait 30 seconds for it to be available
        # (lame, I know, but there's no nc available to start prodding network ports)
        sleep 30
        # Run every script in /scripts
        # TODO set a flag so that this is only done once on creation, 
        #      and not every time the container runs
        for foo in /scripts/*.sql
          do /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -U sa -P $$SA_PASSWORD -l 30 -e -i $$foo
        done
        # So that the container doesn't shut down, sleep this thread
        sleep infinity
```

if i have setup.sql file in scripts folder is this enough ? i had an error

> sql-server-db    | Sqlcmd: '/scripts/*.sql': Invalid filename.

what to change in that .yml file or should i add en extra file to scripts folder ?

Comment: So what executes the .sql file?

Comment: i dont know how it works to be honest i thought that mounting in scripts folder and writing path to that folder with .sql file in volumes will be enough and it will execute it from cmd using docker-compose up command

Comment: Nope, sorry, it won't go looking for and executing files like, say, bash would with `.bashrc`. You need to have your Dockerfile configured to launch the SQL Server process and then run your setup/data script once SQL Server is accepting connections. Here's [an example](https://github.com/twright-msft/mssql-node-docker-demo-app#import-datash).

Comment: And what can i do with that if i am forced to use windows as a host machine and all the linux commands and node is useless there. the entrypoint, import and dockerfile. Is there a way to do this in windows and with .yml file ?

Comment: Why would a Windows host matter? The docker commands themselves run in a Docker container managed by Docker Desktop.

Comment: Also, that example runs up a Node app inside the same container as the SQL Server, which isn't something you'd normally do (i.e.: you'd keep apps in separate containers). Ignore the Node bits, the important parts of that example are 1) it shows you how to execute .sql scripts inside an SQL Server container to create databases, tables, data, etc. and 2) it shows you how such a script should wait for SQL Server to finish launching itself before connecting to do its thing.

Comment: I added an extra change i .yml file, but still en error. this time with wrong filename. I posted changes up in the post

Comment: need help with this, which is connected topic to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465128/docker-compose-yml-file-with-startup-sql-not-working

Comment: Please avoid cross posting. You can't log in simply because your SQL scripts haven't run. That requires someone who knows bash to fix your script in the other question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465128/docker-compose-yml-file-with-startup-sql-not-working?noredirect=1#comment120999698_68465128