# Docker-compose.yml file with startup.sql not working

Tags: sql-server, bash, docker, docker-compose, sqlcmd

I create my MSSQL database docker container with only docker-compose.yml file and setup.sql file. My .yml file looks like that:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  sql-server-db:
    container_name: sql-server-db
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
    ports:
      - "1433:1433"
    environment:
        SA_PASSWORD: "secret123new!"
        ACCEPT_EULA: "Y"
    volumes:
    - ./data/mssql:/scripts/
    command:
      - /bin/bash
      - -c
      - |
        # Launch MSSQL and send to background
        /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr &
        pid=$$!
        # Wait for it to be available
        echo "Waiting for MS SQL to be available ⏳"
        /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -l 30 -S localhost -h-1 -V1 -U sa -P secret123new! -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT \"YAY WE ARE UP\" , @@servername"
        is_up=$$?
        while [ $$is_up -ne 0 ] ; do
          echo -e $$(date)
          /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -l 30 -S localhost -h-1 -V1 -U sa -P secret123new! -Q "SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT \"YAY WE ARE UP\" , @@servername"
          is_up=$$?
          sleep 5
        done
        # Run every script in /scripts
        # TODO set a flag so that this is only done once on creation,
        #      and not every time the container runs
        cd /scripts
        for foo in /scripts/"*.sql"
          do echo "Processing $foo";
        done
        echo "All scripts have been executed. Waiting for MS SQL(pid $$pid) to terminate."
        # Wait on the sqlserver process
        wait $$pi
```

when i try to connect with Dbeaver to set in file user credentials there in an error looks like that:

> Login failed for user 'system'. ClientConnectionId:17e53706-8242-4bca-974b-3648b5ba7f13

there in an extra warning:

> The foo variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string

setup.sql file in /scripts folder mounted on localhost directory mssql on desktop:

```
CREATE DATABASE probna
GO
USE probna
GO
CREATE LOGIN system WITH PASSWORD='system'
GO
CREATE USER system FOR LOGIN system
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] ADD MEMBER system
GO
CREATE TABLE Products (ID int, ProductName nvarchar(max))
GO
```

sql-server-db    | ServiAll scripts have been executed. Waiting for MS SQL(pid 8) to terminate.
sql-server-db    | ce Broker endpoint is in disabled or stopped state.

What could be wrong with this ? my setup.sql file is in /scripts folder. I don t have another files. Should i replace some of the code or some $$ lines ? Please give me some tips how to start docker mssql database with startup file on windows without node.js :) Have a nice day !

Comment: `'/scripts/*.sql': Invalid filename` makes it seem like the bash for loop isn't working. Maybe you could replace `do /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd....` with `do echo "Processing $foo";` to confirm what the path looks like.

Maybe it would work if you first `cd /scripts`

Comment: There are quite a few suggestions here, including double quoting etc. https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-loop-over-file/

Comment: It worked partially because  invalid filename error is now gone but during the connection to database using Dbeaver and user credentials in .sql file there is another error   -  Login failed for user 'system'. ClientConnectionId:17e53706-8242-4bca-974b-3648b5ba7f13               what is more, in cmd there is a warning -  The foo variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.    maybe that is the reason for the failure ? any idea how to set this foo variable or fix this error ? i will add .sql file for you to see if there is an mssql code errors in this

Comment: This is one of those "evolving" questions where the original question gets solved but then you have another issue. Now that your script has `do echo "Processing $foo";` it's obviously not running the SQL script. Instead it's saying "The foo variable is not set" right? You aren't going to be able to log into the db until your script is run. This issue is everything to do with writing bash scripts and nothing to do with SQL

Comment: I removed the database tag and added the bash tag. Hopefully someone who knows about bash can help.

Comment: after `cd /scripts` why don't you put `ls` and see what files it can see?

Comment: To clarify : all changes so far are for troubleshooting only. None of this changes have actually got anything working yet. Forget about the login error until you can get your SQL scripts to run. You won't be able to login until you run the script to create the user.

Comment: OK, so we wait untill someone who knows bash can do something with this

Comment: i think that i miss something in the script that breaks down everything

Comment: It's just a matter of getting the for loop part right. Clearly this was copied from somewhere - can you reference where you copied it? or is it a copy of an existing script?

Comment: I used this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465128/docker-compose-yml-file-with-startup-sql-not-working

Comment: How many sql scripts do you have? if you just want to get this working you can just list them out explicitly